# How to call ajax by jquery on multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have multiple (number may go as high as 500) checkboxes, as follows

```
<?php
$duplicate_checked='';
if ($repeat==1)
{
$duplicate_checked=' checked';
} else {
$duplicate_checked='';
}
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="isrepeat-<?php echo $id_no; ?>" id="isrepeat-<?php echo $id_no; ?>" class ="class_isrepeat" value="<?php echo $id_no;?>" <?php echo $duplicate_checked;?> onclick="updateRepeat(this.checked,<?php echo $id_no;?>);"/><label for="isrepeat-<?php echo $id_no; ?>">Is a duplicate Question?</label>
```

**I want to update the value of Repeat column of the particular question number ($id_no, in this e.g.) in mysql database (e.g. named Qbank) on change of checked value of that checkbox.**

I am able to successfully get checked value in javascript function updateRepeat(value, ques_no); But I couldn't get a way to call ajax by javascript.

In jquery this can be done something like -

```
$('#isrepeat-{question no}').change(function() {
    $.post('update_repeat.php', {ques_no: question_number, repeated: checkbox_value_integer},
    function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
    });
    });
```

**Edit - 1.** `#isrepeat-{question no}` represents id tag of the checkbox depending on question number eg, `#isrepeat-1`, `#isrepeat-2`, `#isrepeat-3` etc.

But, This would require definite question number in "#isrepeat-{question-no}". I dont know how to construct this jquery in a way that it automatically picks question no and checked property for any particular checkbox clicked.

**If I use class, instead of id for checkboxes then, how can i get question number and checkbox checked value for any checkbox in a single function?**

Also, although I have a basic Idea what should be in update_repeat.php for ajax call, it would be nice if you could give any way by which this update can be easily done in ajax.

thanks.
regards,

Comment: `#isrepeat-{question no}` what is this ? can you use some class for this purpose and use `this` to get current changed checkbox

Comment: @susheel '#isrepeat-{question no}' means id number of checkbox depending on question number eg, '#isrepeat-1', '#isrepeat-2', '#isrepeat-3' etc.
Can you please tell me by any e.g. how to use class '.class_isrepeat' to get 'this' value. thanks

Comment: You can use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: @oGeez can you please explain by a small example? thanks.

Comment: wrap each `repeat` in it's own container and traverse within that container. This is a very common pattern. If you want more help you should be providing properly formatted source html in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are correct by utilizing *class* as selection to trigger the function. You can then continue by calling `$(this)` within the trigger callback to utilize the document object for each particular checkbox user clicked on.

Then just use `.attr` to get an input attribute that stores some information.

Which makes the code into

```
$('.class_isrepeat').change(function() {
   question_number = $(this).val();
   checkbox_value_integer = $(this).prop('checked');
   $.post('update_repeat.php', {ques_no: question_number, repeated: checkbox_value_integer},    function(data){
       $("#result").html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: should be using `prop()` for `checked` or simply use `this.checked`

Comment: @charlietfl just one doubt, this code works correctly with `prop()`, while it reverses with `attr` or `this.checked`. (I mean, the later 2 return the state before click) Why is it so?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari without code context I don't understand the issue. Make a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates it

Comment: @charlietfl e.g. if the checkbox is in NOT checked state initially and using the demo function mentioned by Teguh above, if I get the value of `checkbox_value_integer` in an alert box by using `prop()` - it returns true; while using `attr()` or `this.checked` return `undefined` and vice-versa.

Comment: @charlietfl [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/atultiwari/3H9JQ/12/), the `prop` is working while `attr` and `this.value` is not working

Comment: I have no idea what your you expect from your demo @Dr.AtulTiwari